# netsh wlan start hostednetwork. The hosted network started. Stuck @Obtaining ip address

Tags: windows, hotspot

I can create a hosted network via following commands:

```
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow
netsh wlan set hostednetwork ssid=lol key=cse093007 keyusage=persistent
netsh wlan start hostednetwork
```

But I m stuck at obtaining an IP address.

I can't turn on those following two:

```
FIPS 140-2 mode supported : No

802.11w Management Frame Protection supported : No

Interface name: Wi-Fi

    Driver                    : 802.11n/b/g 2cm Wireless LAN USB2.0 Adapter
    Vendor                    : AboCom System, Inc.
    Provider                  : Microsoft
    Date                      : 30-Mar-13
    Version                   : 1086.51.328.2013
    INF file                  : net8192su64.inf
    Type                      : Native Wi-Fi Driver
    Radio types supported     : 802.11n 802.11g 802.11b
    FIPS 140-2 mode supported : No
    802.11w Management Frame Protection supported : No
    Hosted network supported  : Yes
    Authentication and cipher supported in infrastructure mode:
                                Open            None
                                WPA2-Personal   CCMP
                                Open            WEP-40bit
                                Open            WEP-104bit
                                Open            WEP
                                WPA-Enterprise  TKIP
                                WPA-Personal    TKIP
                                WPA2-Enterprise TKIP
                                WPA2-Personal   TKIP
                                WPA-Enterprise  CCMP
                                WPA-Personal    CCMP
                                WPA2-Enterprise CCMP
                                Vendor defined  TKIP
                                Vendor defined  CCMP
    Authentication and cipher supported in ad-hoc mode:
                                Open            None
                                Open            WEP-40bit
                                Open            WEP-104bit
                                Open            WEP
                                WPA2-Personal   CCMP
    Wireless Display Supported: No (Graphics Driver: No, Wi-Fi Driver: No)
```

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes DHCP on windows Ad-Hoc takes too long to assign IP address or sometimes it fails to do so.

So if DHCP is not working properly, use static IP on the client side.

Type `ipconfig` in command prompt and find the IP address of an interface named **Microsoft Hosted Network Virtual Adapter**.

Now, in the client system, use that IP as the default gateway and give the client IP address with first 3 fields same as the default gateway and giving a different number in the 4th field.

eg:

```
Default Gateway : 192.168.43.1
IP Address of client : 192.168.43.3
```

Answer (score 5):

**This fixed my issue. I forgot to share my wifi to hostednetwork.**

To share you wifi with hostednetwork;-

- go to network adapter settings
- right-click on your default wifi adapter
- click on properties
- go to sharing tab
- check on allow other user to connect to this computer
- in drop down menu select your hostednetwork

[image]

Comment: Also make sure there's no firewall interfering with the dishing out of dhcp addresses. https://superuser.com/questions/867394/internet-connection-sharing-with-wireless-hosted-network-whn-is-not-providing

Answer (score 3):

You can try using a static IP address in Phone Wifi settings. Try the following settings.

```
IP Address: 192.168.137.2
Gateway: 192.168.137.1
DNS1: 8.8.8.8
DNS2: 8.8.4.4
```

Answer (score 1):

#### The following procedure worked for me (windows 8.1)

1) Disable Internet Connection Sharing from your modem connection -> properties -> Sharing Tab

2) Enable it again.

3) Disconnect from the Internet.

4) Reconnect again

5) Restart ICS service from the "services.msc" window.

6) Stop the hostednetwork

7) Start the hostednetwork

8) Internet Sharing is now enabled and everything gets resolved.

---

Credit goes to [Vekool](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/profile/vekool?type=forum&referrer=https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4f6f356b-6cbf-43b7-821c-dc4034284b7d/hostednetwork-is-set-up-android-device-is-unable-to-obtain-ip-address?forum=w8itpronetworking)

Answer (score 0):

it also worked for me.

from here: https://superuser.com/questions/804227/how-to-get-assigned-ips-by-hostednetwork

---

I've also had this problem, and I solved it like this:

```
create a WiFi hotspot:

netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=ProvaMi  key=pippo123

netsh wlan start hostednetwork

Assign the hotspot a name in the "Network and sharing center > change adapter settings" (in my case: "TestWIFI")

Set a static IP address for the WiFi network:

netsh interface ip set address "TestWIFI" static 192.168.159.1 255.255.255.0 196.168.159.1
```

Now, using a program that provides a DHCP server on windows (http://www.dhcpserver.de/cms/), I configured the server to generate the

```
[SETTINGS]
IPPOOL_1=192.168.159.2-254
IPBIND_1=192.168.159.1
AssociateBindsToPools=1
```

Now, the DHCP server will update its own settings file (dhcpsrv.ini) with the IP address and the DNS name of any connected client.

Hope this helps.

Note: all the above (IP addresses, passwords, etc.) are examples for my test configuration. Of course you'd need to use your own settings.

Answer (score 0):

Simply restarting the ICS service from the "services.msc" window will fix this. After which, 
run:

`netsh wlan stop host`

`netsh wlan start host`